# definite article with plural hypotheses

Tags: articles, grammatical-number

Is it correct to write  "scientests can test a hypotheses" even though hypotheses is a plural?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. It is not grammatical for a plural noun to be preceded by the indefinite article.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A hypothesis is the singular version and should be used

Otherwise use "can test the hypotheses"